# iOS extensions and cordova : 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova

I have added some iOS extensions to my cordova project and I get the following error for each one of my extensions and custom frameworks :

`'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found`

[image: error screenshot]

But my extensions don't need this file. So what I was doing previously was to simply comment this line and every thing just works fine.

But I recently added a new cordova plugin (written in swift) that need this header. So I cannot comment this line anymore.

How to exclude this particular header of my extensions builds ?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you need to create a bridging header file (Bridging-Header.h for ex.) that contains the import of the CDV.h as follows:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
```

You need to make sure your target build settings has the following:

```
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
```

Bridging headers are the way to expose Objective-C code to Swift.